# Refactor 2 functions with different arguments but almost same implementation in c

Tags: c, function, refactoring

I have 2 functions similar to each other,

```
void func1(info1* ari,int l,int r) {
   int size = sizeof_char_array(ari->field_type) ;
   for (int i=0 ; i<size ; i++) {
      if (ari->field_type[i] & MEMORY) {
         mem_info* mi = (mem_info*)ari->field[i] ;
         mi->L = l ;
      }
      else if ...
      else {
         info2* p = (info2*)ri->field[i] ;
         func2(p,l,r);
      }
   }
}
```

Another one is

```
void func2(info2* ri,int l,int r) {
   int size = sizeof_char_array(ri->field_type) ;
   for (int i=0 ; i<size ; i++) {
      if (ari->field_type[i] & MEMORY) {
         mem_info* mi = (mem_info*)ri->field[i] ;
         mi->L = l ;
      }
      else if...
      else {
         info2* p = (info2*)ri->field[i] ;
         func2(p,l,r);
      }
   }
}
```

It's easy to find that the only difference between this 2 functions are `info1*` and `info2*`. `info1` and `info2` are structs with similar layouts.

Is there a way to refactor this 2 functions to one elegantly in C?

Comment: Note that your `func1` is not recursive (it calls `func2`); your `func2` is recursive (it calls itself).  Is that a typo in the question?  The fragment also uses `info2` and a cast.  Is that really what you want?  If it is, there's a lot of difference between the functions — much more than the surface number of characters to be edited.

Comment: yes, func2 calls itself. the fragment uses info2. @JonathanLeffler

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately C doesn't have a mechanism like [C++'s templates](http://codeofthedamned.com/index.php/fundamentals-of-c-templates). You could use a macro to generate the two functions, parametrizing on the type:

```
#define DEFINE_FUNC(name, type)                          \
    void name(type* ari, int l, int r)                   \
    {                                                    \
        int size = sizeof_char_array(ari->field_type);   \
        for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)                    \
        {                                                \
            if(ari->field_type[i] & MEMORY)              \
            {                                            \
                mem_info* mi = (mem_info*)ari->field[i]; \
                mi->L = l;                               \
            }                                            \
            else if                                      \
            { /* ... */                                  \
            }                                            \
            else                                         \
            {                                            \
                info2* p = (info2*)ri->field[i];         \
                func2(p, l, r);                          \
            }                                            \
        }                                                \
    }
```

Then you can define your functions and use them as follows:

```
DEFINE_FUNC(func1, info1)
DEFINE_FUNC(func2, info2)
#undef DEFINE_FUNC

int main()
{
    func1(some_info1, 0, 5);
    func2(some_info2, 1, 6);
}
```

Comment: what if fun1 call itself recursively? @Vittorio

Comment: @YuanWen: then you just change the invocation of `func1(...)` with `name(...)`.

Comment: Note that the code in the question is misleading; the functions _both_ call `func2` whereas they're probably supposed to be recursive (so `func1` calls `func1` but `func2` calls `func2`).  There's also an issue of `info2` appearing in `func1` — it is not clear whether that is correct, either.